# How can I build a DMD 1.076/Tango bundle (Win32)

Tags: windows, d, 32-bit, tango, d1

Willing to harness Tango library along with the very last release of DMD 1 compiler (v1.076), I searched the net in vain for the bundle.

How that can that be built?

---

### Solved:

I've managed to build a DMD 1 v1.076 with Tango. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16769351/744588) my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a bundle, specifically?

Here is the official bundle download:

http://dsource.org/projects/tango/wiki/TopicInstallTangoDmd

You could also download a newer compiler separately, but Tango may not work with the latest compiler out-of-the-box - you may need to update the code in a few places to get it to build.

---

Tango is no  longer maintained by its creators, which is why the downloads haven't been updated in a while. Some volunteers may be maintaining forks of Tango which work with the latest D versions. For example, here is a D2 fork: https://github.com/SiegeLord/Tango-D2

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm not at all interested in the D2 port (DRUNTIME/PHOBOS is OK). My firm belief is that there should be someone else/somewhere else using DMD 1.076/Tango in production given the bunch of soft written using Tango.

Comment: I think I should ping [larsivi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14047/larsivi): He certainly has more to tell as a prominent contributor of Tango.

Comment: Bunch of software using Tango?? That certainly made me laugh... You can still find larsivi on IRC. He is working on his D-line programming language called Amber.

Comment: As is already mentioned, the bundles from the page linked above were the last made by me. There are however people, even companies, using the latest D1 Tango, with what I think is the latest DMD. They are however compiling the libraries themselves, using one of the several build scripts available.

Comment: @DejanLekic: It seems that the Amber project still relies on Tango as its current compiler isn't at a stage allowing bootstraping for the time being. As an enthusiast, I prefer to harness D1/Tango where language & library were freezed. I meant bunch of soft written **years ago** using Tango. Yet I follow prominent D2 projects such as [vibe.d](http://vibed.org/) to keep abreast of progress/change.

Answer (score 0):

To share my findings:

I finally end up building with success a **DMD 1.076 with Tango as Library (Win32)** Bundle.

I followed the detailed steps mentioned in the [Tango's website](http://dsource.org/projects/tango/wiki/TopicInstallTangoExplicit) regarding Win32 platform.

It works with **DMD 1.071** version onward.

I had to fix one issue by just changing a `private extern (Windows)` line of code to `protected extern (Windows)` in one module.

I noticed that the Tango Library has undergone some changes since bundle I used before (DMD1.056/Tango 0.99.9).